# Tensorflow graph run speed keeps decreasing each iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a very simply tensorflow setup but one aspect of it (calculating the accuracy) keeps increasing in how long it takes to run. I'm confused about why this is. I've simplified down the code as much as I can while stile keeping the error. Here is the code

```
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# dummy data
data = np.zeros((12, 784))
labels = np.zeros((12, 10))

xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [12, 784])
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [12, 10])

weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784, 10], stddev=0.1))

prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(xs, weights))

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

while True:

    y_pre = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={xs: data})
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pre, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    start_time = time.time()

    r = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={xs: data, ys: labels})

    time_taken = time.time() - start_time

    #why does time_taken keep growing?
    print("time_taken", time_taken)
```

I suspect it's something I'm doing wrong in the while True loop. For my experience time_taken starts of low around 0.01 but then seemingly indefinitely grows to 0.30 and beyond if you leave it long enough. Is there some way to keep the time_taken constant? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you take a look at your RAM during execution?

Comment: Ram usage seems to go up by about 3 MB/s as it runs.

Comment: Hm. This is quite weird. If I am right it should stay same, since you are not creating new data.  Does it stop going up after a few minutes?

Comment: No the memory usage keeps growing. The rate at which the memory grows does slow down but I think that's due to the program itself slowing down. I left it on for some time and time_taken started out as 0.00399 and ended with 3.6614, and memory usage of the program tripled.

Comment: Can you check your globals and see if the garbagecollector is actually working? https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/globals